# Get generated HTML from mediawiki API query

Tags: mediawiki-api

My script posts the following fields to a MediaWiki api to get the content of all the pages in a given category. Right now it provides the wikitext of the article but I would like the rendered HTML.

I've been reviewing the [API instructions](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Brevisions) and playing around with the contentmodel but no luck.

What do I need to change?

```
$postdata = ['action' => 'query', 'format' => 'php', 'prop' => 'revisions', 'rvprop' => 'content', 'generator' => 'categorymembers', 'gcmtitle' => 'Category:'.$category];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rvparse` parameter ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=phpfm&prop=revisions&generator=categorymembers&rvprop=content&rvparse=1&gcmtitle=Category:Middle_Ages)). Not that it is deprecated, with no replacement wrt. using generators. If you don't care about generators, you can use [action=parse](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse) but it's probably easier to just avoid the API and use [action=render](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php#Actions), or use [the REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#!/Page_content/get_page_html_title) if you prefer the different flavor of HTML it returns.